# socket.io slow only when a message emit from server to the client,while it is very fast from server to the client sent the message

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, socket.io

The problem:
 
when the client sent a message to the server there is a delay to emit the message to the other client
  while the same message sent super fast to the client that sent the message
 
i.e
 
Client A --> Server --> Client A Super fast
 
Client A --> Server --> Client B a bit slower
 
i am using socket.io NodeJs/Express , nginx web server(tested in Apache same issue)

i noticed that in safari and also in mobile chrome
 
**edit below is the nginx config**

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
pid     /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;
http {
    include    mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    sendfile    on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    client_max_body_size 200M;      
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;   
    server_tokens off;  
    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}

server {
    listen      *:443 ssl ;
    server_name wsapidev.sample.com www.wsapidev.sample.com;    
    error_log   /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/wsapidev.sample.com.err;
    access_log  /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/wsapidev.sample.com.log main; 
     ssl                            on;
    ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/cert/wsapidev.sample.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private/wsapidev.sample.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam             /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem;   
location  /socket {       
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";   
      proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:44451/socket;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're getting a webSocket connection for socket.io and it's not just polling?  There are some case where mismatched versions of client/server or misconfigured network infrastructure can prevent the proper socket.io connection that should be fast both directions and can end up with the client polling which can manifest itself as slower data coming from the server to the client.

Comment: yes i am pretty sure it is websocket connection,only websocket as transport
also i checked the header response it is upgraded to websocket in all browsers that i test
socketIo(this.server, { pingTimeout: 60000,pingInterval:10000, transports: ['websocket'], path: "/socket" ,allowUpgrades:true}); and it is only slow when server sends the message to other client,while when sent to the same client it is super fast

Comment: Is your client busy doing something else and doesn't get free to process the incoming data right away?

Comment: nop,my server doing nothing,since my project is in a dev stage,jut 2 clients runnig for testing.i read about Nagle's algorithm,since when i send multiple messages together all they received exactly at the same time(with delay),but why the issue is only as i said in safari and from server to other client while to the same client is super fast(client A safari to client B chrome super fast,client A chrome to safari delay,chrome to chrome super fast)

Comment: How much of a delay are you talking about?

Comment: depends 3-10 sec,btw when i change pingInterval to 1 sec it works fine

Comment: If changing `pingInterval` to 1s makes the delay go away, then it's likely a networking infrastructure or config problem somewhere.  You mention nginx so I'd look at that configuration too.  That long a delay has nothing to do with Nagel's algorithm.

Comment: server {
 listen  *:443 ssl ;
 server_name wsapidev.sample.com www.wsapidev.sample.com;   
  ssl       on;
 ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/cert/wsapidev.sample.com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key   /etc/ssl/private/wsapidev.sample.com.key;
 ssl_dhparam    /etc/ssl/private/dhparam.pem;  
location  /socket {        
      # enable WebSockets
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:44451/socket;    
        } 
}

Comment: #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;
pid  /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
 worker_connections  1024;
}
error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;
http {
 include    mime.types;
 default_type  application/octet-stream;
 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

Comment: sendfile on;
 #tcp_nopush  on;
         tcp_nodelay on;
 #keepalive_timeout  0;
 keepalive_timeout  65;
 #gzip  on;
 client_max_body_size 200M; 
 # If your domain names are long, increase this parameter.
 server_names_hash_bucket_size 64; 
 # To hide the version number in headers
 server_tokens off; 
 include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}

Comment: It doesn't really work to put multiline stuff line this in comments.  We can't really read it.  You can add it to the end of your question, format it appropriately and then leave a comment indicating what you added to your question.

Comment: i added the nginx config in the question

Comment: It seems that it's likely a timeout configuration on nginx where it's timing out your websocket connections unless you have a really active ping.  I don't know nginx well enough to know which timeout setting to suggest you configure or increase.   With event driven servers (like nodejs), it's much less important to have short timeouts for inactive http connections too.

Comment: FYI, one thing you can do for diagnosis purposes is to log all the connect, disconnect, reconnect, error, etc... events on both client and server (after you increase the ping interval back to normal) and see if you can see the disconnections happening.

Comment: after diagnosis,i found that the issue is the WIFI,when i am using WIFI on my iphone there is a delay while if i m using the 5G it works super fast,strange: since on my laptop it is super fast (using WIFI connection),not sure right now how to get fixed

Comment: That's odd that your laptop would work fine over the same WiFi access point as your phone.  Any chance the 5G WiFi is using some extension of the WiFi protocol that your phone is having trouble with, but your laptop is OK with?  Or the signal is weak to your phone?